# Change bitrate of MP3 using .Net Core Azure Functions

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, mp3, naudio

I am trying to create an Azure Function using NAudio / NLayer.NAudioSupport, in which I can pass in a URL (such as https://file-examples-com.github.io/uploads/2017/11/file_example_MP3_1MG.mp3), read the bytes, and return the mp3 file converted at 128Kbps. However I'm currently getting an exception stating:

> System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function : ReduceMp3Bitrate. NAudio.Lame: unsupported encoding format MpegLayer3 (Parameter `format`).

Here's my current code (Exception occurs on Line 5):

```
const string linkUrl = @"https://file-examples-com.github.io/uploads/2017/11/file_example_MP3_1MG.mp3";
var audioFile = new HttpClient().GetByteArrayAsync(linkUrl);
await using var ms = new MemoryStream(await audioFile);
var audioReader = new Mp3FileReader(ms);
await using var audioWriter = new LameMP3FileWriter(@"C:\temp\test.mp3", audioReader.Mp3WaveFormat, LAMEPreset.ABR_128);
await audioReader.CopyToAsync(audioWriter);
```

I think the issue is with `audioReader.Mp3WaveFormat`, but I'm not sure why this would be the issue, as it's returning `MpegLayer3`.

I've also tried running this on a .Net Framework 4.7 console application running on Windows (taking Azure Functions out the equation) and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Change the audioReader.Mp3WaveFormat to audioReader.WaveFormat (in line 5).

Explanation: As mentioned in https://github.com/naudio/NAudio/blob/master/NAudio/Wave/WaveStreams/Mp3FileReader.cs#L28  Mp3WaveFormat is NOT the output format of the Mp3FileReader stream. That is present in WaveFormat.